# Declare a whole string with a single charcter

Tags: c, arrays, string

When declaring an array in C I can write `int array[100]={0}` and it assigns 0 to all index. Is there any way to do the same thing with string? Because when I write `char string[100]={'A'}` it only assigns 'A' to the first index.And when I print the string it displays "A" instead of what I want "AAAAA.....A(99 times)". I dont want to use a loop to assign all the indexes with 'A'. So what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure "*it assigns 0 to all index*"? Also, if you want to print the string `"AAAAA"`, you need `char string[7] = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '\0'};`

Comment: "I don't want to use a loop to assign all the indexes with 'A'" -- That's what would be happening under the hood anyway, and C very intentionally hides as little as possible.

Comment: Yes i have tried it with array. It assigns all the index with 0. And what you say about your string is true.But what to do when the length of the string is much greater and is not easy to declare.

Comment: "char string[100]={'A'} it only assigns 'A' to the first index." --> No. Initialization is all or nothing. The remaining elements are 0.

Comment: @chux yes thats the problem.I want to assign the rest elements with 'A' with a single declaration.

Comment: Yes, with `char string[100]={'A'}` all the  variable is assigned  in a single declaration.  "rest elements with 'A' with a single declaration"  is inconsistent with "I want "AAAAA.....A(99 times)" as the 100th is not defined. If you want `"AAA (99 total) AAA"`, use `"AAA (99 total) AAA"`

Comment: In particular  a _string_ in C includes the terminating null character, so the the only whole _string_ of all the same character is`""`

Comment: You can just loop: `char string[100] ={0}; for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++) string[i] = 'A';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not in the standard but some compilers (including [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) and clang that I tested it with on my system) allow this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  char str[100] = {[0 ... 98] = 'A'};
  str[99]='\0';  // this line is really not necessary, since default is 0 and I just wrote it for clarity 
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's part of GNU extensions and that link is the documentation for gcc 4.1.2. So I cannot find a reason for not working with gcc 4.x. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C does not have a mechanism for what you want.  In particular, note that the two cases you describe are the same: that `int array[100]={0}` causes the array to be initialized with all zeroes is not because the specified 0 is applied to all elements, but rather that the specified 0 is applied to the zero<sup>th</sup> element, and all otherwise uninitialized elements are initialized with a default value, which *coincidentally* is specified to be 0.  Initialization of the `char` array follows the same rule.

If you want to initialize 99 elements of an array to 'A', then the initializer must provide 99 'A's.  If you want to avoid typing (and counting) them all, then you might use a macro to assist:

```
#define REPEAT11(x) x x x x x x x x x x x
char string[100] = REPEAT11("AAAAAAAAA");
```

That makes use of compile-time concatenation of adjacent string literals to form the wanted initializer.

Comment: thanks for clearing out my idea about array. Should have tried with something other than zero.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`memset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) from `<string.h>` to fill the first n bytes of your array with `'A'` characters. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    /* initializes all elements to 0. */
    /* Will not work with 'A' as the default values of this array are 0 */
    char array[SIZE] = {0}; 

    /* fills first 99 bytes with 'A', and leaves last byte as '\0' */
    memset(array, 'A', sizeof(array)-1);

    printf("array = %s\n", array);
    printf("length of array = %zu\n", strlen(array));

    /* Outputs:
       array = AAAAAAAAA...
       length of array = 99
    */

    return 0;
}
```